# Firebase A/B testing runs concurrently for Android and iOS in one testing

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-ab-testing

I have the App which runs in Android and iOS. I want do Firebase A/B testing in this two platform concurrently in one testing. But I need to choose the platform (Android or iOS)in the setting of A/B testing before running the A/B testing.

I am wondering is it possible to set the A/B testing concurrently for Android and iOS in one test instead of two separating test? Thanks

Comment: not possible, even the docs say so, you will need separate configs for iOS and Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible. I guess this is because apps on different systems usually will not have exactly the same behaviour and users. Thus on one platform test might give you a very positive result, but you wouldn't notice that because result is offset by another platform.

One way to achieve what you want is to (obviously) create two tests OR create RemoteConfig and roll it out to X % of random users (see ["User in random percentile"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#condition_rule_types)), then set userProperty / send Event and based on that information in which group is the user, analyze the data in [BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en).